# Fabric.js: How to make do not take areas of invisible elements in a group?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to make group having invisible element.
I have a plan to make the element visible or invisible. 
But the group takes the invisible element's area when selecting.
So how to make do not take area of invisible element in group?
Or are there other ways which are not 'visible: true/false'?
http://jsfiddle.net/o2duat5k/

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid red"/>
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
        top : 0,
        left : 0,
        width : 60,
        height : 70,
        visible: false,
        fill : 'red'
    });
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
          radius: 100,
          fill: '#eef',
          scaleY: 0.5,
          originX: 'center',
          originY: 'center'
        });

        var text = new fabric.Text('hello world', {
          fontSize: 30,
          originX: 'center',
          originY: 'center'
        });

        var group = new fabric.Group([ circle, text ], {
          left: 150,
          top: 100,
          angle: -10
        });
        var group2 = new fabric.Group([ rect, group ], {
          left: 150,
          top: 100,
          angle: -10
        });
        canvas.add(group2);
        canvas.renderAll();
        group2.setCoords();
```

Comment: Do you actually use fabric v1.2.0 as you do in your fiddle?

Comment: Thank you for your concern. It seems not related to fabric.js  version. I think now that it maybe is the best way that removing the invisible element and adding the visible element.

Comment: Yes, it's not about the version, of course. I have a solution that would require an override of an internal method though, so it is somewhat dependent on the version.

Comment: What is it? I have an idea that make an invisible element be positioned above other visible elements in group, but for the condition when it could be, I'd appreciate if you let me know about the solution.